Difference between an ANCOVA and an ANOVA on residuals that the effects of covariates are already removed
My psychological experiment has a repeated-measures design. Each participant performed 4 conditions (Factor A [2 levels] X Factor B [2 levels]). Let say the DV is the accuracy of the participants and and the IVs are Factors A and B, and I am interested in the interaction between Factors A and B. I also want to control for the participants' IQs and ages. Therefore, I performed a repeated measures two-way ANCOVA (Factor A X Factor B) with IQ and age as the covariates.
Since I want to plot the mean accuracy for each condition separately with the effects of the covariates removed, I am trying a different approach to do the ANCOVA. First, I separately regressed the accuracy on IQ and age for each condition. Then, I put the residuals from the regressions into a repeated measures ANOVA (Factor A X Factor B; no covariate). But I realized the results are quite different from the abovementioned ANCOVA. Could anyone explain if I have done something wrong?
I tried running a linear regression to remove the effects of covariates followed by a simple correlation, to replace a partial correlation. So I am thinking it will also work for the abovementioned ANOVA case. If I have any misunderstanding, could anyone correct me? Thank you so much!

If you present the residuals as new data then the model you're applying can say nothing directly or indirectly about the effects you've already removed. Everything depends on whether that matches your goals. I am no psychologist but I have to guess that IQ and Age are interesting and possibly important controls. You may well be more interested in variation they don't explain, but for most purposes they should be part of the model so that anyone else sees the full picture.

This is an ad hoc approach in the sense that it is highly dependent on goodness of fit of a linear model.  Many situations require other models, e.g., ties or floor/ceiling effects require ordinal regression models.  Those don’t have residuals, and all effects of interest are obtained by using contrasts.

I came here to add some thoughts which I now guess overlap with one point that @Frank Harrell is making. An extra problem is that even if residuals are defined, the approach in effect assumes that they are certain. But in practice even with ANOVA, the structure may not be exactly additive, and so forth. Otherwise put, the residuals are estimated and it's disingenuous or worse to treat them as if they are observed.

@NickCox Thank you for your comment! To my knowledge, adding covariates means to remove all the variance explained by the covariates. Am I correct? If this is the case, then the new model saying nothing directly or indirectly about the effects I have already removed should be sensible? And this is what I actually want to achieve but I found that the ANOVA testing on the residuals does not results in the same conclusion as the original ANCOVA. Could you let me know if I performed something wrong statistically? Thank you.

@FrankHarrell Thank you for your comment! My DV is continuous data and hence I think  I am correct to get the residuals from a linear regression model? The thing I am most confused by is that, as described in my original question, I performed this ad hoc approach to replace a partial correlation analysis and it worked. But now it doesn't work for the repeated measures ANOVA case. I am not good at statistics. Could you please let me know what the difference between these two cases is? Thank you.

I don’t think I can add helpfully to what has already been said. What you did earlier may have seemed to work but ad hoc remains a short judgment and it’s not here a commendation.

@NickCox Thank you so much!
